# Extract rows from csv files in R

Tags: r

I want to extract lat/long data + file name from csv

I have done the following:

```
#libraries-----
library(readr)
library("dplyr")
library("tidyverse")


# set wd-----EXAMPLE
setwd("F:/mydata/myfiles/allcsv")

# have R read files as list -----
list <- list.files("F:/mydata/myfiles/allcsv", pattern=NULL, all.files=FALSE,
                  full.names=FALSE)
list
]

#lapply function
row.names<- c("Date=0", "Time=3", "Type=2", "Model=1", "Coordinates=nextrow", "Latitude = 38.3356", "Longitude = 51.3323")
AllData <- lapply(list, read.table, 
                  skip=5, header=FALSE, sep=";", row.names=row.names, col.names=NULL)

PulledRows <- 
  lapply(AllData, function(DF) 
    DF[fileone$Latitude==38.3356, fileone$Longitude==51.3323]
  )

# maybe i need to specify a for loop?
```

[how my data looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix1sf.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Is the data uniform across all csv files? i.e. is latitude always in cell 6? Or at least always says Latitude=....?

Comment: Yes. They always occur in the same cell and say "Latitude=#$#%$" and same for longitude. The values change however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. You may have to change the path location if the .csv files are not in your working directory. And the location to save the final results.

```
results <- data.frame(Latitude=NA,Longitude=NA,FileName=NA) #create empty dataframe
for(i in 1:length(list)){ # loop through each file obtained from list (called above)
  dat <- read_csv(list[i],col_names = FALSE) # read in the ith dataset
  df <- data.frame(dat[6,1],dat[7,1],list[i]) # create new dataframe with values from dat
  df[,1] <- as.numeric(str_remove(df[,1],'Latitude=')) # remove text and make numeric
  df[,2] <- as.numeric(str_remove(df[,2],'Longitude='))
  names(df) <- names(results) # having the same column names allows next line
  results <- rbind(results,df) # 'stacks' the results dataframe and df dataframe
}
results <- na.omit(results) # remove missing values (first row)
write_csv(results,'desired/path')
```

Comment: I added some comments to my answer. This isn't really a great place to teach you line by line, etc. but you're on the right track. I'd spend some time dissecting it and trying to understand what each line does. Topics here could be subsetting dataframes, for-loops, etc.